# create ms sql server job schedule from datetime database

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, schedule

I'm using microsoft SQL server management studio 2005

I'm trying to run a job at a specific time and that time is stored in a database.

I can't insert the schedule manually because it is up to the user to decide what date and time the job(s) has to be done. php collects the time and date and sends it to a database.

I thought about runing a job every min and in my execution I have an if statement that only activates when the datetime stored in the database is one minute greater or lower than the current datetime. but doing it like this would be inaccurate and very inefficient. would it be possible to create a schedule directly from a query or job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and modify both [jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.aspx) and [schedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobschedule.aspx) programmatically using SMO or [TSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366342.aspx). That means you can use an external application, a stored procedure or a trigger to create or update a job schedule based on the table data. SMO is probably the best way to go if you want to build an application to manage jobs, but on the other hand it's .NET only.

Comment: Thanks! the TSQL is exactly what I needed! sorry for the late reply!